# Get the MAC address of a local network device knowing its IP

Tags: android, ip-address

I have a device on my local network. I know its MAC address, and want to find its IP. Because android doesn't seem to allow sending direct ARP queries (unless I'm mistaken), I've decided to take another approach: I scan all available devices on the local network.

That's where I'm stuck. I now have a list of IPs, and would like to check their MAC address to find which one is the one I'm looking for.

Could any of you please recommend a way to proceed?

Comment: please check it may it will some help you-   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39335835/how-to-get-ip-address-and-names-of-all-devices-in-local-network-on-android