# How to resolve Ipv4 and Ipv6 from ".local" using mDNS in Android

Tags: android, ipv6, multicast, ipv4, mdns

I am trying to resolve IPv4 and IpV6 from ".local" using multicast DNS and I tried https://github.com/posicks/mdnsjava but it unable to resolve required ipv4/ipv6. Alternatively, I found one app  which work for me but have no idea how it works.

**App Link :** https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dokoden.dotlocalfinder

Also I am trying to resolve ".local" using `Linux` Terminal -

Command used to resolve ipv4
`avahi-resolve-host-name abc.local -4` 
Command used to resolve ipv6
`avahi-resolve-host-name abc.local -6`

and it resolved successfully.

I am  tried same command in Android to resolve ".local" but getting **Cannot run program "avahi-resolve-host-name": error=13, Permission denied**

I am trying this piece of code in Android -

```
  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("avahi-resolve-host-name abc.local -4");
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
  Log.d("OutPut",in.readLine());
```

Comment: Try running it with elevated permissions, with sudo

Comment: Thanks @rombie18 ,I also tried with root privilege but not get success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I got success.

I resolved Ipv4 and Ipv6 using **mdnsjava** dependency i.e.

```
implementation "xyz.gianlu.mdnsjava:mdnsjava:2.2.1"
```

For resolving Ipv4 I use this code snippet

```
for (Record record : new Lookup(localName, Type.A, DClass.IN).lookupRecords()) {
   if (record.getType() == Type.A) {
       ((ARecord) record).getAddress().getHostAddress();
       }
    }
```

Before writing this code snippet you have to put MuticastLock on connected Wifi using

```
  WifiManager.MulticastLock multicastLoc = wifiManager.createMulticastLock("mDnsLock");
  multicastLoc.setReferenceCounted(true);
  multicastLoc.acquire();
```

and after getting ip release multicastLock.

For Ipv6 I used same Ipv4 code snippet only here the record type should be `Type.AAAA` in place of `Type.A`

This code works up to Android 10.

Comment: People won't easily notice supplementary questions in answers. If you still have a problem then you can either (a) edit your existing question, if the questions are tightly connected; or (b) ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% this will work, but as comment is was to large.

1. check the following permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

2. Following links might be usefull:

- [How to get IP address and names of all devices in local network on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39335835/how-to-get-ip-address-and-names-of-all-devices-in-local-network-on-android/39339881)
- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan
- https://github.com/stealthcopter/AndroidNetworkTools